# Displaying function result in other file

Tags: php, function

I've got two files: `function.php` and `cobafunction.php`.

I have code in `function.php` as follows:

```
function pegawai (){
$getpegawai = mysql_query
("select * from pegawai where nip ='005970458'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array ($getpegawai);

echo "$result[nip]";

}
```

How do I make `echo "$result[nip]";` be displayed in another file that is in `cobafunction.php`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php static function like this

> cobafunction.php

```
class yourClassName {
    static function pegawai (){
        $getpegawai = mysql_query("select * from pegawai where nip ='005970458'");
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($getpegawai);
        return $result['nip'];
    }
}
```

> another file

```
echo yourClassName::pegawai();
```

Try it !

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be something like:

```
function pegawai() {
    $getpegawai = mysql_query("select * from pegawai where nip ='005970458'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array ($getpegawai);

    return $result[nip];
}

$someVariable = pegawai();
```

And you should include the `function.php` on the `cobafunction.php` file.

Comment: I agree that returning the result instead of echoing it from within pegawai() is better, even though I didn't write my answer that way.

Comment: That's a safer and (I guess?) faster way to accomplish what he needs.

Comment: I agree, but I think what he is having trouble with is the include/require in the coba file.

Answer (score 0):

You can call pegawai() from cobafunction.php

Example:

```
//cobafunction.php
<?php
require_once("function.php")
pegawai()
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the pegawai function, instead of:

```
echo "$result[nip]";
```

I would do:

```
return($result[nip]);
```

In cobafunction.php

```
include("function.php");

$var = pegawai();
print $var;
```

Comment: Note that the pegawai() function already has an echo but does not return anything.

Comment: I see that.  Edited my answer to not do that for more flexibility.

Comment: You should switch to mysqli or pdo for connecting the the database.  The mysql functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and removed in 7.0.